How to collect terms with respect to exp(ikx) from a product of trigonometric functions and exponential functions? (Make it like a Fourier expansion)
I have a product: $\sin(k_0(x-A_0))(e^{ik(B_1 x+A_1)}-e^{-ik(B_2 x+A_2)})$.
I would like to rewrite it as a sum in a form of $\Sigma_{k'} C_{k'}e^{ik'x}$, namely, to make it like a Fourier expansion.
How should I do it in mathematica?

Try Expand[TrigToExp[expr]].

I tried TrigToExp[Sin[a x + b] (E^(I c x + d) - E^(I e x + f))] // Expand and it gave $1/2 I E^(-I a x-I b+I c x+d)-1/2 I E^(I a x+I b+I c x+d)-1/2 I E^(-I a x-I b+I e x+f)+1/2 I E^(I a x+I b+I e x+f)$. The x terms aren't collected together. I want the result to be in an exact form of $\Sigma_k C_k exp(i k x)$.

It might help to look at this question then: my answer there explains how to separate the exponential factors in each term.
